# Submenu disappears in Chrome, Safari and Firefox on Mac OS 10.6

Tags: html, css, macos

When I hover over the payer apps menu and try to click one of the items in the submenu the submenu disappears at http://curo.creativedynamite.co.uk on every page.

I'm running Max OS 10.7 and it works in my Chrome, Firefox and Safari but it doesn't on my friends' who runs Snow Leopard (OS 10.6).

I have been trying to figure out why this is, at first I thought it was due to the Slider and the header images and the CSS positioning I was using:

```
<div id="navigation" class="clearfix">
        <div class="menu-main-menu-container"><ul><li><li id="menu-item-212" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-212"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-25" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-25"><a href="http://curo.creativedynamite.co.uk/our-approach">Our Approach</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-592" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-592"><a href="#">Payer Apps</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-105" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-105"><a href="http://curo.creativedynamite.co.uk/payer-apps/payerlogic">PayerLogic</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-107" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-107"><a href="http://curo.creativedynamite.co.uk/payer-apps/accessaccelerator">AccessAccelerator</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-106" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-106"><a href="http://curo.creativedynamite.co.uk/payer-apps/charisma">CharismA</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-108" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-108"><a href="http://curo.creativedynamite.co.uk/payer-apps/r3tracker">R3Tracker</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-104" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-104"><a href="http://curo.creativedynamite.co.uk/payer-apps/prescriberlogic">PrescriberLogic</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-23" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-23"><a href="http://curo.creativedynamite.co.uk/about-us">About Us</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-22" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-22"><a href="http://curo.creativedynamite.co.uk/careers">Careers</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-21" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-21"><a href="http://curo.creativedynamite.co.uk/blog">Blog</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-20" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-20"><a href="http://curo.creativedynamite.co.uk/news">News</a></li>
</li></ul></div>    </div><!-- navigation -->

/* Navigation */
#navigation { min-height:30px; height:60px; margin-left:-20px; }
    #navigation ul { list-style-type:none; text-align:center; padding:20px 0 0 0;}
        #navigation ul li { list-style-image:none; padding:0.2em 1.8em; /* 0.3 1.3 with 7 menu options*/ font-size:1.3em; float:left; }
        #navigation ul li a { color:#9d9fa0; padding:6px 10px; }
            #navigation ul li a:hover { background:url("../images/bg_menu.gif") repeat-x left top #868888; color:#fff; text-decoration:none; padding:6px 10px; }
                #navigation .current_page_item a { background:url("../images/bg_menu.gif") repeat-x left top #868888; color:#fff; padding:6px 10px; }

                    #navigation .current_page_item a, .current_page_item a:hover, .current_page_item a:visited { color:#fff; }

/* Navigation - Drop down menu 
#navigation li ul.sub-menu li { position:absolute; left:-999em; height:auto; width:190px; font-weight:normal; margin:0; line-height:1; border-top:1px solid #cccccc; }*/

#navigation ul ul {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    display: none;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top:9em;
    left: 55.6  em;
    width: 168px;
    z-index: 99999;
    background-color:#fff;
}
#navigation ul ul li {
    padding:0 0em;
}

#navigation ul ul ul {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
#navigation ul ul li a {
    color:#9d9fa0;
    font-size:14px; 
    font-weight: bold;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 0em;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    width: 175px;
}
#navigation ul ul :hover > a {
    background:url("../images/bg_menu.gif") repeat-x left top #868888; color:#fff;
}
#navigation ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
#navigation .current-menu-item > a,
#navigation .current-menu-ancestor > a,
#navigation .current_page_item > a,
#navigation .current_page_ancestor > a {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Does anyone have any thoughts on this please?

Comment: There's no good reason why it would work in one OS and not another.  Usually, rendering problems occur between browser brands and not operating systems.  Does your HTML code properly validate?  Do you get any console errors?

Comment: You've tagged your question with HTML yet there is no HTML code.  You've mentioned _"payer apps, Slider, and header images"_ but don't provide a demo or link.  Please [read this page](http://sscce.org/) and fix your question... we're not mind-readers.

Comment: Sorry about that Sparky672 I have edited it as per that page.

Comment: The [HTML Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fcuro.creativedynamite.co.uk%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) indicates lots of malformed tags.

Comment: Ok I have cleared the mal formed elements inside of the Navigation menu can anyone tell me if the menu works as it should do please.

Comment: You missed an important one... _"Line 322, Column 6: end tag for element `div` which is not open"_

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?  Please "accept" my answer below if it solved your problem.  If not, please add the actual solution below and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `top:9em;` from this...

```
#navigation ul ul {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    display: none;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top:9em; 
    left: 55.6  em;
    width: 168px;
    z-index: 99999;
    background-color:#fff;
}
```

That puts the submenu back where it can touch the bottom edge of the menu button which allows the mouse to get inside of it.  It was the gap between the menu button and the submenu drawer causing your problems, because the mouse cannot get across the gap without losing focus of the `:hover` item.